# How do I get animation for my sticky navigation bar to work in both directions when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here's a link to my test blog for reference](http://www.finesttest.blogspot.com/)

Thanks to TylerH, I've got the animation set for when I scroll *down*, but I'd like that animation to reverse when I scroll back up. I'm going to assume that I need an additional javascript function for that to work, so for the time being:

Here is the new CSS (with added .unfixed property):

```
sticknav {
background: #b50000;
height: 46px;
width: 1080px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 413px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
border-bottom: 4px solid #e50000;
webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
}
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    animation: fill 333ms forwards ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: fill 333ms forwards ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes fill {
    from {margin-left: 413px; width: 1080px;}
    to {margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fill {
    from {margin-left: 413px; width: 1080px;}
    to {margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;}
}
.unfixed {
    position:fixed;
    animation: unfill 333ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: unfill 333ms ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes unfill {
    from {margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;}
    to {{margin-left: 413px; width: 1080px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes unfill {
    from {margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;}
    to {{margin-left: 413px; width: 1080px;}
}
```

Here is the Javascript that does with the sticky navigation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var aboveHeight = 205;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
        $('sticknav').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','60px');
        } else {
       $('sticknav').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top','0');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I need to find a way to activate .unfixed once .fixed deactivates, but that sounds complicated. I'll need it to activate only after the user scrolls back up after .fixed activates. Yeah, that sounds complicated, any help would be appreciated. Hopefully there's an easier way.
An example of what I want exactly can be found on [Game Rebels](http://www.gamerebels.com).

Comment: Can you make a jsfiiddle.com or something so we can try your code and see if we can get it to work?  You might get more people to look at it if you make it easier for us.

Comment: Yeah I don't know if that's quite possible. I'll see what I can do but for now I'll add a link to my blog.

Comment: @MarkSchauer Can you also work to add the requisite HTML to the post itself? It would help to have a self-contained demo in the post rather than have to go to your blog to see the code in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple solution to your problem. In order to use `animation` and keep the end result, rather than have it reset upon completion, you need to apply an [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode).

Move your animation to `.fixed` instead of `.sticknav` (this will make the animation play when `.fixed` is added on scroll-down, rather than at page load), and add the `animation-fill-mode`:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    animation: fill 11s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

I would also strongly recommend that you use external CSS files, rather than putting all your CSS in `<style>` tags.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but then it won't perform the animation again once I scroll back up and then down again.

Comment: Scratch that, it works. Thanks a lot! Now, is there a way to make it slowly go back to position when I scroll back up, instead of popping right back? Would fill mode "both" do that?

Comment: @MarkSchauer In order to achieve that you might need to swap out classes; e.g. `if { on scroll up, class = .fixed, remove .class & add .standard }` or something (I don't know JavaScript very well so the syntax obviously will be a bit different, but that's the gist of it). Then create a `.default` class with an animation named `unfill` or something and give it `@keyframes` that essentially do the reverse of what your original `@keyframes` are doing.

Comment: @MarkSchauer Alternatively, you could move the `animation` back to `.sticknav` and/or just then use JavaScript to play the animation(s) on scroll down/up.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll look into it, but my coding skills are lacking. But I guess that's what the Internet is for, yes?

Edit: I think I know what I have to do. I'll update this if it works or not.

Comment: That's a no-go. In order to have the animation play in reverse, it also needs to be position: fixed. If I do that, then there's nothing to remove the .unfixed property. If I add the class to the Javascript, it overrides the .fixed property. I need to find a way to have .unfixed enable only when .fixed deactivates, and then find a way to deactivate .unfixed after the animation stops to place the navigation bar in its original place.

Comment: I can try to take a look when I get home at some JS to get it working on scroll up

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm sure it's something really simple, and I'm trying to tinker with it, but it's being rather uncooperative.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code and use CSS `transition` property instead of `animation` which looks simpler unlike `animation`

```
stickynav{ 
     background: #b50000;
     height: 46px;
     width: 1080px;
     margin-right: 0px;
     margin-left: 413px;
     left: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 9999;
     border-bottom: 4px solid #e50000;
     webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
     box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
     transition:width 500ms; //Add this
}
.fixed { 
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:0px;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
}
```

You `js` would be:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight)
           $('stickynav').addClass('fixed')
        else
           $('stickynav').removeClass('fixed')
});
```

Comment: This would make the header jump to the left and then expand out to the right edge of the screen.

Comment: @TylerH. Give me a moment.. let me create a demo for you.

Comment: I added these to the site OP included into his post; it's the behavior I observed.

Comment: The reason it's called stickynav is to allow the navigation to be sticky in the first place. In my HTML, I use <stickynav> and </stickynav> to know what to grab for the fixed header. I used a tutorial for this, so if it's terribly inefficient I apologize. I'm sure the name doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Can you give the complete code for css relating to the above elements?

Comment: Could you specify what would help you the most?

Comment: @MarkSchauer. I couldn't create a demo for you as there is no relevant css but just try the updated answer above and keep the syles in `stickynav` itself

Comment: @MarkSchauer.. The CSS which can create same style as you have in your blog so that I can put it in fiddle and give a demo!

Comment: It's a lot of CSS—and the code you gave doesn't seem to do the trick. In my OP, I've linked another forum that has a navigation bar like I want it. I already managed to get a sticky navigation bar, I just want it to increase to 100% width once it activates in case there was some confusion. Give me a few moments to add all of the CSS to my OP.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: The only other question I have is on @TylerH's answer, if you can help with that.

Comment: Yes you can give option as `both` instead of `forwards`. Check this **[link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp)**

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. I probably need another Javascript function to reverse the animation because right now it resets to normal when I scroll back up.

Comment: or place transition property in `.fixed` class and try?

Answer (score 0):

Working solution

Try `margin-left: 92px;` instead of `margin-left: 413px`

```
sticknav {
   background: #b50000;
   height: 46px;
   width: 1080px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   margin-left: 92px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 9999;
   border-bottom: 4px solid #e50000;
   webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
   box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
   animation-name: fill;
   animation-duration: 12s;
}
```

Output

[image]